# Regex parsing substring

Tags: java, regex

I have the string "http://www.google.com/search?q=Regular+Expressions&num=1000"
and I have been trying to get the substring after the third / (inclusive), while stopping before characters such as ?, #, and whitespace

So far, I have the regex

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:.*?\\/){3}([^?#]+)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This regex works partially meaning that it captures everything after the third / but I cannot get it to include the /. I want to include it because I want to be able to know where I found the start of the substring that I am trying to capture.

For the string "http://www.google.com/", it does not capture anything, so I cannot tell where the substring started for the regex

How can I improve my regex to include the third / and capture everything after excluding ? and #?

Comment: Why not use a URL parser and not worry about it?

Comment: Trying to learn, and use regex primarily

Comment: One of the best things to understand about regexes is that there are times they're not the best tool for the job and you'll cause yourself avoidable grief using them in those situations. It doesn't include the third `/` because it's part of your "preamble" match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
.*\/\/.*(\/[^?#]+)
```

Moving the / inside the parans adds it to the capture group.

https://regex101.com/r/yZZUDc/1